# Van der Waerden Theorem - Deducing Ackermann function Upper bound

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, ramsey-theory, extremal-combinatorics

According to the book "Ramsey Theory on the Integers, Landman", the original proof of Van der Waerden's Theorem yields the upper bound ack(n) for w(k;2).

I didn't quite understand the proof that book gave but I read this one and it was quite clear: [http://www.sfu.ca/~vjungic/RamseyNotes/sec_proof_vdW.html](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Evjungic/RamseyNotes/sec_proof_vdW.html)

Is there a way to deduce this ackermann function upperbound (or a similar one) from the proof in this link?

Answer (score 0):

It's more that there's a bound which grows roughly like the Ackermann function, with some other things happening that are less relevant. (Although I did see the actually-literally-Ackermann bound in Landman and Robertson's book, it's not clear to me if that's meant to be taken literally.)

From the prove you give, let's define $F(\ell, k, r)$ to be the least $M$ such that if $[1,M]$ is $k$-colored, there is either

- a monochromatic $\ell$-term arithmetic progression, or
- $r$ color-focused $(\ell-1)$-term arithmetic progressions.

The proof gives us three inequalities:

1. $F(\ell,k,1) \le 2W(\ell-1,k)$.
2. $F(\ell,k,r) \le 2 F(\ell, k, r-1) \cdot W(\ell-1, k^{2 F(\ell,k,r-1)})$.
3. $W(\ell,k) \le 2 F(\ell,k,k)$.

Define two related functions $w(\ell,k)$ and $f(\ell,k,r)$ by:

1. $f(\ell,k,1) = w(\ell-1,k)$.
2. $f(\ell,k,r) = w(\ell-1, f(\ell,k,r-1))$.
3. $w(\ell,k) = f(\ell,k,k)$.

These are a sort of "lower bound on the upper bound": we have stripped away the less-relevant parts of the recursions in the upper bounds on $W$ and $F$. In one sense, $w$ and $f$ will end up much smaller than $W$ and $F$: where $F(\ell,k,r)$ has a $k^{2 F(\ell,k,r-1)}$ in its recursion, $f(\ell,k,r)$ just has $f(\ell,k,r-1)$. But when we get to Ackermann-sized bounds, the difference between these two things is insignificant, so $w$ and $f$ still capture the essence of the growth rate of $W$ and $F$.

So where does the Ackermann function come in? Well, the recurrence for $f$ and $w$ unpacks into
$$
   w(\ell,k) = w(\ell-1, w(\ell-1, w(\ell-1, \dots w(\ell-1,k)\dots)))
$$
with $k$ applications of $w$, and the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) satisfies $A(m,n) = A(m-1,A(m,n-1))$ and $A(m,0) = A(m-1,1)$ from which we get
$$
   A(m,n) = A(m-1, A(m-1, A(m-1, \dots A(m-1,1)\dots)))
$$
with $n$ applications of $A$. These aren't quite the same, and may not have the same base cases (actually, I haven't said what the base case for $w$ is). But they will still follow the same pattern that $A(m,\bullet)$ is a nested application of $A(m-1,\bullet)$ and $w(\ell,\bullet)$ is a nested application of $w(\ell-1,\bullet)$. If at one "level" (one value of $m$ or of $\ell$ respectively) the function grows like addition, then at the next it will grow like multiplication, at the next like exponentiation, at the next like power towers, and so on through the [Knuth up-arrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't quite understand the reason why the functions you give (f and w) behave similarly to F and W, in terms of growth. It doesn't even seem entirely intuitive to me

Comment: One idea is that once you get to functions as big as Ackermann, there is a very tiny difference between $f$ and $2^f$, for instance.